# omnetpp: Are gate names global?

Tags: omnet++

I am creating an omnetpp simulation of message passing processes. Each process module has an in gate and an out gate for message passing. Are these gate names global. i.e. do I have to assign a new gate name to each process when I create it in my C++ code?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the names of gates have only local meaning, i.e. gate name has to be unique only in the module.